# Unexpected Token ILLEGAL while adding shard sh.addShard in mongos

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database

I am going through this post https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sharded-cluster-in-mongodb-using-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

I have 3 config , 2 query and 4 shards 
I am succesfully able to ssh and login into every droplet

But in ***"Add Shards to the cluster"*** section

whenever i do

`sh.addShard( "shard-01.my-domain.com:27017” )`

it gives me

```
2017-01-19T14:10:10.487+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

even if i do it with ip

`sh.addShard( "xxx.59.39.62:27017” )`

it gives me

```
2017-01-19T14:10:10.487+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

IS there anything which i am doing wrong ? syntax is similar to the one described on the link and everywhere

'xxx just to hide the IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using curly quotes instead of normal quotes:

```
"shard-01.my-domain.com:27017”
```

do this:

```
"shard-01.my-domain.com:27017"
```

Some text editors tend to do that sometimes.